# How do you get items from txt into presentable table in bash?

Tags: bash, git-bash

I'm trying to retrieve items from Node01.pc and put it within a table.

Example:
`echo ${NodeCPU[0]}` is able to print the item from the line.

But when I use printf or echo it either breaks or does not display the output from the array item.

The formating of the table seems work and it displays only if it's not the arrays. Could it be that there's more than to the file that I can see?

Node01.pc contains

```
192.168.0.99
2
70
16
80
4
4
100
4

VS122:NMAD:20:20:1:1
VS122:NAMD:20:20:1:1
RS123:FEM:10:20:1:1
QV999:BEM:20:20:1:1
```

But I only need lines 3,5,7,9

I'm not sure if what is the best way to do this, or if I even need to store items into arrays.

I thought about retrieving all text from the texts files and making a new file which will contain all the data, but I'm not sure how to do that.

This is the code that I have right now.

```
#!/bin/bash

Node01=($(cat Node01.pc))
Node02=($(cat Node02.pc))
Node03=($(cat Node03.pc))
Node04=($(cat Node04.pc))
Node05=($(cat Node05.pc))

NodeCPU=("${Node01[2]}" "${Node02[2]}" "${Node03[2]}" "${Node04[2]}" "${Node05[2]}")
NodeMEM=("${Node01[4]}" "${Node02[4]}" "${Node03[4]}" "${Node04[4]}" "${Node05[4]}")
NodeHDD=("${Node01[6]}" "${Node02[6]}" "${Node03[6]}" "${Node04[6]}" "${Node05[6]}")
NodeNET=("${Node01[8]}" "${Node02[8]}" "${Node03[8]}" "${Node04[8]}" "${Node05[8]}")

seperator=----------------------
seperator=$seperator$seperator
rows="%-10s| %-7s| %-7s| %-7s| %-7s\n"
TableWidth=140

printf "%-10s| %-7s| %-7s| %-7s| %-7s\n" NodeNumber CPU MEM HDD NET
printf "%.${TableWidth}s\n" "$seperator"

for((i=0;i<=4;i++))
do
    printf "$rows" "$(( $i+1 ))" "${NodeCPU[i]}" "${NodeMEM[i]}" "${NodeHDD[i]}" "${NodeNET[i]}" 
    
done

read
```

This is an example of what I want to display

```
NodeNumber | CPU | MEM | HDD | NET
----------------------------------
1          | 10  |  20 |  20 | 40
2          | 10  |  20 |  20 | 40
3          | 10  |  20 |  20 | 40
4          | 10  |  20 |  20 | 40
5          | 10  |  20 |  20 | 40
```

EDIT This is what I'm currently getting:

```
NodeNumber| CPU    | MEM    | HDD    | NET
--------------------------------------------
     | 4  | 70
     | 5  | 90
     | 6  | 100
     | 6  | 70
     | 40 | 40
```

Issue I'm having is with

`printf "$rows" "$(( $i+1 ))" "${NodeCPU[i]}" "${NodeMEM[i]}" "${NodeHDD[i]}" "${NodeNET[i]}"`

Comment: You showed what output you want, what output do you get right now? What section of your code does not do what you want it to do?  See [mcve]

Comment: I tried your code with sample files I created, the format is what you want.  Add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why worry about all the separate array? Simply loop over all `"Node*.pc"` files in the current directory and read the contents of each file into an array with `readarray` and then output the file count and elements nos. `2, 4, 6, 8` of the array in the proper format (adjust elements output as needed), e.g.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cnt=1   ## file counter

## print heading
printf "NodeNumber | CPU | MEM | HDD | NET\n----------------------------------\n"

for i in Node*.pc; do           ## loop over all Node*.pc files in directory
    readarray -t node < "$i"    ## read contents into array
    ## output count and elements 2, 4, 6, 8 in proper format
    printf "%-11s| %-4s| %-4s| %-4s| %s\n" $((cnt++)) \
    "${node[2]}" "${node[4]}" "${node[6]}" "${node[8]}" 
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

With the example data shown copied to the file `Node01.pc` in the current directory, you would get:

```
$ bash node.sh
NodeNumber | CPU | MEM | HDD | NET
----------------------------------
1          | 70  | 80  | 4   | 4
```

(I called the script `node.sh`)

It would output the information from each file as separate lines numbered `1, 2, ...` Look things over an let me know if this is what you intended. (you can also do the same thing with `awk` faster by setting `FS=\n` and treating the lines as columns in a single record)

You can do the same thing in `awk` with:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        RS=""; FS="\n"
        printf "NodeNumber | CPU | MEM | HDD | NET\n----------------------------------\n"
    } 
    NF >= 9 {
        printf "%-11s| %-4s| %-4s| %-4s| %s\n",++cnt,$3,$5,$7,$9
    }
' Node*.pc
```

(**note:** in `awk` the field numbers are 1-based, while in bash the array indexes are 0-based)

Output is the same.

Comment: This does seem to be an more effective way of processing but when reading mutiple nodes, it ends up with the same output as I showed before.

Comment: awk method is working fine. I think the problem occured in reading the file with the for loops. Seems that the data obtained with for loop has hidden characters, thus needing to format the files.

Comment: There is also the possibility your file contains DOS carriage returns. `awk` generally handles that better than bash.

Comment: You can check by opening an xterm and running `dos2unix Node01.pc` and then trying the bash script again. I have no issue with one file or multiple files with the bash script (I just copied `cp Node01.pc Node02.pc` to test). Works the same with either bash or awk scripts above.